# Alternate tensorflow hub module tags in runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have a standard pipeline that evaluates the model after training an epoch. I *need* resnet50 to be finetunable while training, so I instantiate like so:

```
resnet50_module = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/resnet_v2_50/feature_vector/1",
                             trainable=True, name="resnet50_finetunable", tags={"train"})
```

However, I read [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/24#issuecomment-390133942) that I should unset the tags when evaluating.

I realize that I can save the model, close the session, reset the graph, rebuild the model with the `tags=None` and load the weights from a checkpoint to do the eval. This seems very wasteful specially since the size of the model is huge due to resnet50, and I need to do hundreds of epochs to get good results. Is there a way to alternate between tags without this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no good way to do this without going through a checkpoint.

Variables are created when hub.Module() is called, so they are tied to a particular graph version (tags={"train"} for training or the empty tag set for inference). What you describe could be read as a feature request to set that separately for each application of the module, but that doesn't exist yet (and has some ramifications).

Is checkpointing to local disk really that expensive compared to the eval you want to run? Wouldn't you want to checkpoint at times anyways, to allow resuming after a crash?

Comment: I'm already checkpointing after each train epoch. I just felt that resetting the graph and rebuilding it over and over again would be wasteful, specially since I'd do it twice per epoch: once to eval and then again to train. But if it doesn't exist I can use the workaround.